# How to target a instance with something other than instanceID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lambda

The goal i am trying to achieve is I have around 8 test instances that i want to stop when i am not at work to save cost. then start them back up again when i get back to work.

I have a function that achieves exactly what i need

```
import boto3
region = 'cn-north-1'
instances = ['i-xxxxxx', 'i-xxxxxxx', 'i-xxxxxx', 'i-xxxxxx', 'i-xxxxxxxx']
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print('stopped your instances: ' + str(instances))
```

The problem is I have immutable deployment policy on all of my instances so `instances` is constantly changing and i will have to update the function everyday.

Is there anyway that I can target by tag or something more versatile so i don't have to update the function everyday?

I've looked through documentation but it's pretty unclear to me
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people should use the instance scheduler, but you can't in the China region.

**Alternate Solution**

There are dozens of samples on the internet that will help you achieve this. One of them is [here](https://gist.github.com/gregarious-repo/b75eb8cb34e9b3644542c81fa7c7c23b). Basically, instead of hard coding instance IDs you use the boto3 API to find instances by tag.

This function also lets you change the start / stop time using tags. You can take parts of this code and modify yours (which came from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/) I think) to incorporate it.

```
import boto3
import time

##
# First function will try to filter for EC2 instances that contain a tag named `Scheduled` which is set to `True`
# If that condition is meet function will compare current time (H:M) to a value of the additional tags which defines the trigger `ScheduleStop` or `ScheduleStart`.
# Value of the `ScheduleStop` or `ScheduleStart` must be in the following format `H:M` - example `09:00`  
# 
# In order to trigger this function make sure to setup CloudWatch event which will be executed every minute. 
# Following Lambda Function needs a role with permission to start and stop EC2 instances and writhe to CloudWatch logs.
# 
# Example EC2 Instance tags: 
# 
# Scheduled     : True
# ScheduleStart : 06:00
# ScheduleStop  : 18:00
##

#define boto3 the connection
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get current time in format H:M
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M")

    # Find all the instances that are tagged with Scheduled:True
    filters = [{
            'Name': 'tag:Scheduled',
            'Values': ['True']
        }
    ]

    # Search all the instances which contains scheduled filter 
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)

    stopInstances = []   
    startInstances = []   

    # Locate all instances that are tagged to start or stop.
    for instance in instances:

        for tag in instance.tags:

            if tag['Key'] == 'ScheduleStop':

                if tag['Value'] == current_time:

                    stopInstances.append(instance.id)

                    pass

                pass

            if tag['Key'] == 'ScheduleStart':

                if tag['Value'] == current_time:

                    startInstances.append(instance.id)

                    pass

                pass

            pass

        pass

    print current_time

    # shut down all instances tagged to stop. 
    if len(stopInstances) > 0:
        # perform the shutdown
        stop = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=stopInstances).stop()
        print stop
    else:
        print "No instances to shutdown."

    # start instances tagged to stop. 
    if len(startInstances) > 0:
        # perform the start
        start = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=startInstances).start()
        print start
    else:
        print "No instances to start."
```

**Standard Solution**

This is the best solution for most people.

Use the [AWS instance scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/instance-scheduler/), as per [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/instance-scheduler/). It starts and stops instances based on tags, on a schedule you define.

I'm not going to copy and paste an article in here, as the information changes occasionally and AWS keeps their documentation up to date quite well.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not available in the `cn-north-1` region:(

Comment: I have added another option for you to the answer

Comment: Nice Tim! this looks like the proper solution for me